# FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR fgd size

Tags: windows, clipboard, ole

Looking at FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

cItems = The number of elements in fgd

however the size of fgd is fixed to 1 in the struct declaration, so whats the point of cItems?

Comment: Classic C does not support variable-sized arrays, so a dummy size of 1 is used for declaration purposes.

Comment: Why can it not be FILEDESCRIPTOR* fgd?

Comment: Because it's a clipboard format. Imagine what would happen if you put a `FILEDESCRIPTOR *fgd` on the clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

It's a common pattern used for allocating items dynamically:

```
int items = 5;
int cb = sizeof(FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR) + (items - 1) * sizeof(FILEDESCRIPTOR);
LPFILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR lp = (LPFILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR)new BYTE[cb];
lp->cItems = items;
for(int i = 0; i < items; i++)
{
    lp->fgd[i].blah = blah;
}
```